Power BI dashboard with slicers that are additive and can recognize individual cell contents
I’m working on a Power BI dashboard and need help with setting up slicers to filter my data effectively. Here's the situation:
I have a table with columns for Primary Responsibility and Secondary Responsibility. The goal is to:

Use a slicer to filter the data based on Primary Responsibility.
Then, use a second slicer that is additive to the previous slicer (i.e., doesn't limit my options given my selection in the previous slicer) for Secondary Responsibility.

The challenge is that some cells in the Secondary Responsibility column contain multiple departments (e.g., "Department Y; Department P"). I’d like the slicer to recognize these departments as individual items so I can filter them separately (e.g., "Department Y" and "Department P" as distinct options).
What’s the best way to handle this in Power BI?  Below is the current data setup.
enter image description here


In PowerQuery, reference your main query, then remove all columns except for TASKS and SECONDARY RESPONSIBILITY.
Still in PowerQuery, split column SECONDARY RESPONSIBILITY by delimiter ;  (semi-colon & {space}), ensure Split into is set to Rows.
Come out of PowerQuery, then create a relationship between this new Table and your previous table.
Use this new table for your second slicer.

